# unwanted broadcasting in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

I want to execute

```
for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
    a= sigmoid(np.dot(w, a) + b)
```

where,
a is a tuple of length `784`,
self.biases contains a list of matrices of dimensions `(15, 1)` and `(10, 1)`,
self.weights contains a list of matrices of dimensions `(15, 784)` and `(10, 15)`.

So, I am basically calculating `w.a + b` in each pass through the loop. Upon doing this calculation with w of size `(15, 784)`, a of length 784 and b of size `(15, 1)`, I should get the resultant matrix of size `(15, 1)` but I am getting `(15, 15)`.

To debug, I tried to analyse by printing the various matrices involved and I found that if I removed `+ b` from the above line of code, I get the dimensions of the resultant matrix as `(15,)`.

So, **I am guessing that the bug should be because of some inadequate type of matrix broadcasting happening in the code**.

I tried to remove the bug by adding the following lines of code before the for loop:

```
a= np.array(a)
np.reshape(a, (784, 1))
```

But it failed to improve the result.

Please help..

Comment: Your solution is 99% correct. Only `reshape` doesn't work in-place, so reassign!

Comment: What shape should `a` have in the end?

Comment: @hpaulj After each pass through the loop, `a` should have the same shape as `b` does

Comment: Then `a` should start as an array with the same shape.